# ADO.NET add SQLParameters

Tags: ado.net

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with parameters using ADO.NET in .NET Core.

When I try and pass in a SqlParameter object I get the below error.
I have a using statement at the top for System.Data.SqlClient.
Is there another way or new ways of passing Sql parameters to a stored procedure?

```
 public async Task<List<SynchStockDto>> GetStockForSync(int locationBinId, DateTime lastSyncDate)
        {
            await EnsureConnectionOpenAsync();

            var command = GetConnection().CreateCommand();

            command.CommandText = "sp_GetStockForSync @LocationBinId, @LastSyncDate";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Transaction = GetActiveTransaction();           

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LocationBinId",locationBinId)); //not finding SQLParameter method


            using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    var result = new List<SynchStockDto>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var stockItem = new SynchStockDto
                        {
                         

                        };

                        result.Add(stockItem);
                    }
                    return result;
                }
           
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text, not hard-to-read images. Images can't be copied, tested or googled. In any case, EF already generates parameterized queries from LINQ queries, passing any variables as parameters. The only place where you'd need to explicitly specify parameters is in `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated`. EF isn't used to work with DbConnections and DbCommands directly, these are ADO.NET classes

Comment: sorry posted code

Comment: EF Core 5+ use the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, which replaced System.Data.SqlClient. Is the code referencing the wrong library perhaps?

Comment: You genius thanks that solved it.  Add answer so I can mark as answered.

Comment: Its wierd that I was not given that as a potential fix to add the namespace.